# Trouble in installing odbc to connect excel to sql

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, vba

I installed the correct version of odbc via http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ using this link http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/

On the Start menu (windows 7), I choose Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools, and then click Data Sources (ODBC). But I cannot find the option MySql ODBC 5.1 Driver as shown in http://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/create_new_data_source.png

What can be the problem? What is wrong that i cannot see the option MySql ODBC 5.1 Driver as shown in http://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/create_new_data_source.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed the 32 bit version of the driver, but you use the 64 bit version of the ODBC Administration tool - or the other way round.

If you have installed the 32bit version of the driver, you need to start the 32 bit version of the ODBC Admin tool: `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

For the 64 bit version of the driver, start the 64 bit version of the ODBC Admin tool: `C:\Windows\System32\odbca32.exe` (yes, the naming schema is somewhat confusing).

Note that if you have installed the 32 bit version of the driver, client applications that want to use this driver need to 32bit too - and the same for 64bit: The 64 bit driver works only with 64 bit client applicatons.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am a newbie in it. 

So What is the difference between a driver and the ODBC?